# How to distinguish touch and tap in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a jquery which run on window Pc and iPad. But in ipad it click twice. 
The code is :

```
$("#texthighlight2").on('click,tap,touch',function(){

})
```

Comment: `on('click tap touch'` There are no commas here.

Comment: To find out which one was raised: `event.type`

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
$('#texthighlight2').on('click tap', function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Ignore clicks if there are taps or touches:

```
var ignoreClick = false;
$("#texthighlight2").on('click tap touch', function(e){
  switch (e.type) {
    case 'tap':
    case 'touch': ignoreClick = true; break;
    case 'click': if (ignoreClick) return;
  }
  // ...
});
```

---

Perhaps more usable as a plugin:

```
$.fn.touch = function(handler){
  var ignoreClick = false;
  return this.on('click tap touch', function(e){
    switch (e.type) {
      case 'tap':
      case 'touch': ignoreClick = true; break;
      case 'click': if (ignoreClick) return;
    }
    handler.call(this, e);
  });
};
```

Usage:

```
$('#texthighlight2').touch(function(){
  // ...
});
```